# how to improve perfromance of EventProcessorHost's receiving?

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

I donnt know how to improve performance of EventHub's receiving.Now,i am using eventprocessorHost to receive data and the code is almost the demo of eventhub document,i have set options.MaxBatchSize to improve that,but it cannot meet performance .
So,i wonder to know if there is other api of eventhub that can enhance performance ?

````cpp
namespace RecieveFrom
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Registering EventProcessor...");
            string _guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string eventProcessorHostName = _guid;//lease id
            string leasename = eventProcessorHostName = _guid;//lease id
            var eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(
                eventProcessorHostName,
                EventHubName,
                PartitionReceiver.DefaultConsumerGroupName,
                EventHubConnectionString,
                StorageConnectionString,
                leasename);
            //options 
            var options = new EventProcessorOptions
            {
                InitialOffsetProvider = (partitonId) => EventPosition.FromEnqueuedTime(DateTime.UtcNow - new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0))
            };
            options.MaxBatchSize = 10000;
            options.PrefetchCount = 3000;
         eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor>(options);
            Console.WriteLine("Receiving. Press ENTER to stop worker.");
            Console.ReadLine();
// Disposes of the Event Processor Host
            await eventProcessorHost.UnregisterEventProcessorAsync();
        }
//class for data rec
        public class SimpleEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
        {
            public Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.CloseReason reason)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{context.PartitionId}', Reason: '{reason}'.");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
           public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"SimpleEventProcessor initialized. Partition: '{context.PartitionId}'");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
           public Task ProcessErrorAsync(PartitionContext context, Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error on Partition: {context.PartitionId}, Error: {error.Message}");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
//process data
            public Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
            {
                foreach (var eventData in messages)
                {
                    //get data 
                    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```

I expect the performance to be 100,000 rows/min.
````

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official Best practices Guide - [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#prefetching-and-receivebatch)

Since you have asked you need to process

> I expect the performance to be 100,000 rows/min.

Check out [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/processing-100-000-events-per-second-on-azure-functions/) as well

I found the below blogs are helping as well for the performance testing. You can check them as well

- https://mrfoxsql.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/tuning-throughput-azure-event-hub-azure-stream-analytics/
- https://vincentlauzon.com/2018/06/05/event-hubs-ingestion-performance-and-throughput/